# word-wrap in table not working (table-layout:fixed)

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

```
http://74.52.155.226/~projtest/team/harmeet/reach/
```

That is the link i am working on. Its a responsive design. If you see down below the footer there is a table. When you reduce the resolution less than 600px or so the table layout changes. What i cannot do is make the test in first row ( in the small layout ) to have word-wrap as the text is going out of the table cell. Any help? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: you can search for the term "unlimited support" on the page and you will know which row i am talking about. I repeat, please reduce the browser size to see the issue.

Comment: When I reduce browser width, only two data columns of the table are visible, others are available via horizontal scrolling only, when using Firefox. Not really my cup of responsive tea... So is there some more fundamental issue to be fixed first?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Is there a better way to do what i am doing, if yes please let me know as this has been a great deal of hassle for me (make table responsive). And yes this is what its supposed to behave like.

Comment: I don’t see any `word-wrap` in the CSS code.

Comment: I am currently working on it so it was removed sorry. the line#2617 has #rt1 td{} which contains the word-wrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in firebug I can see that you have 'white-space: nowrap' on the tbody element, when in the narrower layout.
You can remove it, or set it to another value i.e. 'normal'

```
#rt1 tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 273px;
}
```

Comment: You are my hero! I've been at it for more than 90 mins and i found a solution. What i did was put white-space: normal; in the td where i wanted the text to wrap but not remove from where you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great :) firebug or another console is the best way to debug these kinds of things. Please accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: I did use it, couldn't get this far without it. Thanks again.